# Google Visualization API chart in Blogger / Blogspot

Tags: visualization, blogger, google-visualization, blogspot

Is it possible to embed (chart) visualizations created by the [Google Visualization API](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/interactive_charts.html) in a Blogger post?

I tried stripping out the `<head>` and `<body>` tags (and closing tags) from the [pie chart example](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/using_overview.html), however, the pie chart visualization fails to render, even on a published post.

**NOTE**: I'm asking about the Visualization API, rather than the [Google Image Charts (Charts API)](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image_charts.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to add the timeline chart, it's not a very straight forward way, but it worked.

Add this to the template of your blog in the `<head>`:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
```

Then when you go to your post, write everything out and click edit HTML. Paste the rest of the javascript in, but remove any returns or they will be automatically replaced by 
 tag inserted by the blogger editor. Save it and you should be ready to go.

Please let me know if you have a specific chart you want to show and I'll try to make it work.

Comment: I doubt I would have ever figured out the complication with the returns. What a gotcha! Many thanks!

Comment: Very welcome! :)   It's pretty strange - only way to catch it is to view source on the post itself. Glad I could help!